# Autocomplete search query in PHP MVC with JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, model-view-controller

I am currently developing a website, and I need do have an autocomplete search so that we can find our user faster, and more precisely. I am using a MVC structure in PHP with a database using mySQL, and I found that JQuery was the best library to use (even tho i never did JS). For now, I have an error : `Uncaught TypeError: this.source is not a function`. I'll show you my structure, along with my script :

```js
$(function() {
    var arrayTenant = 
    $.ajax({
        url:'Models/Admin.php',
        data:{Admin:arrayTenant},
        success:function(yes){
            console.log(yes)
        }
    });

   $( "#automplete_tenant" ).autocomplete({
      source: arrayTenant,
      autoFocus:true
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here are the images of my structure :

[Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6Rpg.png) [View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4Fcm.png) [Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTk5x.png)

Comment: `$.ajax()` doesn't return the response. It makes the call asynchronously and will trigger the "success" callback with the response as the function argument (your `yes` variable). You need to put `$( "#automplete_tenant" ).autocomplete({....})` inside the callback and use the `yes` variable instead of the `arrayTenant` variable in it. Make sure you read through [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for `$.ajax()` to learn how it should be used.

Comment: [You should also not post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Code is text. Copy/paste it into the question directly, like you've done with the javascript

Comment: If you search for something like `jquery ajax autocomplete` on google and/or here on Stack Overflow, you will find many questions/answers about how you can use the autocomplete function. I saw several that put a function as `source`, where they make the ajax request instead.

Comment: Alright thank you for your advice ! I'll try to fix it now.